# Optimize with variable number of input functions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, convex-optimization

I started with following simple optimization problem:

`F=@(L) max(-[log(L(1)/(L(1)+1)) log(L(2)/(L(2)+1))+log(1-L(1)) log(L(3)/(L(3)+1))+log(1-L(1))+log(1-L(2))]);
[L,fval]=fmincon(F,[0.5 0.5 0.5],[],[],[],[],[0;0;0],[1;1;1])`

This gives answers: `L =    0.2554    0.3759    0.7785` and `fval =    1.5925`

However, I need variable number of input functions for `Obj` in `max(-[Obj])`. In above example, I have three functions, i.e.,

`Obj=log(L(1)/(L(1)+1)) log(L(2)/(L(2)+1))+log(1-L(1)) log(L(3)/(L(3)+1))+log(1-L(1))+log(1-L(2))`

I used following code to generate `Obj` in which the number of functions depends on `M`.

```
M = 3;
for i = 1:M
    L(i) = sym(['L(' num2str(i) ')'])
end

tempL = log(1-L);
for m=1:M 
Obj(1,m) =  log((L(m))/(1+L(m))) + sum(tempL(1:m-1));
end
Obj
```

This exactly gives the same `Obj` as above example, but when I pass this `Obj` to following optimization function, it does not support.

```
F=@(L) max(-[Obj]);
[L,fval]=fmincon(F,[0.5 0.5 0.5],[],[],[],[],[0;0;0],[1;1;1])
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue? Because `M` can vary more than 20. It is difficult to enter all functions manually.

Answer (score 0):

### I'd prefer to write some function like this:

Instead you should write some MATLAB function which takes in a vector and returns a scalar, where the value of the returned scalar is the value of your function. Create a separate matlab file (eg. myfunction.m) and do something like:

```
function result = myfunction(L)

M = length(L);

log_one_minus_L = log(1 - L);
log_L           = log(L);
log_one_plus_L  = log(1 + L);


sumsum_templ    = (M-1:-1:1) * log_one_minus_L(1:end-1);
result = sum(log_L - log_one_plus_L) + sumsum_templ;
```

Make sure your function myfunction works by testing on various values. Eg. `myfunction([0; 1])` and see if it returns the right value.

To optimize, then you can call `fmincon(myfunction, ...)` fmincon requires a pointer to a function that takes in a vector and returns a scalar.

Comment: Can you please tell me (directly) how this can be applied to my case since I have variable `M`?